# Issue accessing variable value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am using a Google extension to gather information from a website form, manipulate that information and change the extension's dropdowns dependent on that information.

```
<html>
 <body>
    <h3>Templates</h3>
        <select id="dropdownprimary"></select>
        <select id="dropdownsecondary">
                <option value="BLANK">Choose One</option>
        </select>
    <script src='ddprimaryLoad.js'></script>
    <script src='dropdownprimary.js'></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When the extension icon is clicked, 'ddprimaryLoad.js' runs 'formvalues.js' which gathers the information from the website form.  I then want to use variables from 'formvalues.js' in 'ddprimaryLoad.js'.  The goal is to populate the dropdown depending on the variable, but I have edited that long code down into an alert (The long code didn't work either).

'ddprimaryLoad.js':

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;

chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "formValues.js"
});
storage.get(a,function(result){
    var b = a;
    alert('2nd ' + b);  //This will NOT display
});
```

'formvalues.js':

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
var a = document.getElementById('name').value;
var obj= {};
obj[a] = a;
storage.set(obj);
storage.get(a,function(result){
    var b = a;
    alert('1st ' + b);  //This will display
});
```

The alerts in 'formvalues.js' display however I can't get the information into 'ddprimaryLoad.js'.  I have attempted doing this same process many, many different ways, but this seemed like it would work.  Am I missing something in this process or is there a better way?  I am also happy to bypass 'formvalues.js' but when ...

```
var c = document.getElementById('name').value;
alert (c);
```

...is placed in 'ddprimaryLoad.js' it also does not work.

Comment: there is no element with `id=name`.

Comment: also I think in the callback for `storage.get` you wont get the result in the variable `a` but in the callback parameter `result`. So don't do `var b = a` but `var b = result`.

Comment: @Pascal Rosin The element 'id=name' comes from the website.  var b = a does bring up the correct alert in 'formvalues.js' though.  I will switch it and try.

Comment: ah ok, now I understand. The `alert(b)` in formvalues.js is working because you are using the global variable `a` and not the `result` got from the local storage.

Comment: @Pascal Rosin I have changed the code to ``storage.get(a,function(result){
 var c = result;
 alert('1st ' + c);
});`` and the alert that I get is "1st [object Object]".

Comment: yeah, you need to get your value from the right property of the stored object. But you gave the property an unknown name. With `obj[a] = ` you gave it the name of the value of `a`. You should give it a known name like `"a"` or maybe better `"name"`. Like `obj["name"] = a` and then get it with `var b = result["name"]`

Comment: and the get function needs to get the property's name too: `storage.get('name', function(result) {...`

Comment: Adam, looks like you expect the code to run sequentially which it doesn't. All of chrome.* API invokes callbacks asynchronously. You can find tutorials on how to reorganize the code including the modern await/async approach.